# Inform parent process about child get signal after signal handler in child process is served

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, ipc

Hi currently I am collecting backtrace of child process in signal handler of child process . Then planning to send collected backtrace to parent process using message queue .
My problem is when child process get any signal. child signal handler runs but informs parent process that child exited normally instead of child get signal.
below is my code

```
void childProcess()
{
    int h =0 ;
    for(h=0;h<10;h++)
    {
        printf("child for loop running %d\n",h);
        //sleep(1);
        int q = 1/0; // generate floating point exception
    }

    exit(0);
}



void signalhandler(int signum, siginfo_t *si, void *arg)
{
    printf("signal received %s\n",strsignal(signum));
    printf("%d\n",signum);
    void *array[100];
    int size = 100;
    int addrLen = backtrace(&array,size);
    char ** sym = backtrace_symbols(&array,addrLen);
    int j = 0;
    printf("Test crashed due to %s\n",strsignal(signum));
    for(j=0;j<addrLen;j++)
    {
        printf("%u : %s\n",array[j],sym[j]);
    }
    raise(signum);             
    exit(signum);
}

void registerSignals()
{

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = signalhandler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);       
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &sa, NULL);

}

int main()
{
    //while(1)
    {
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            // child
            printf("child process id is %d\n",getpid());
            registerSignals();
            childProcess();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("parent process id is %d\n",getpid());
            // parent
            int iStatus;
            pid_t childPID = waitpid(pid,&iStatus,0);
            printf("iStatus is %d\n",WIFEXITED(iStatus));
            if(childPID == -1)
            {
                printf("wait pid failed\n");
            }
            else if(WIFEXITED(iStatus)==1)
            {
                printf("child exited normally!\n");
            }
            else if (WIFSIGNALED(iStatus)==1)
            {
                printf("child process terminated abnormally !!\n");
                int iSignalnumber = 0;
                // to fetch the signal number
                iSignalnumber = WTERMSIG(iStatus);
                printf("child process terminated due to %s\n",strsignal(iSignalnumber));
                // to check core file is generated or not
                if(WCOREDUMP(iStatus)==1)
                {
                    printf("core file is generated \n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("core file is not generated \n");
                }
            }
            int h ;
            for(h = 0; h<10;h++)
            {
                printf("parent executing : %d\n",h);
            }
        }
        printf("while loop executing with pid : %d \n", getpid());
        sleep(1);
    }

}
```

My requirement is after signal handler is served in child process the
parent should print "child process terminated abnormally !!" but I am
getting "child exited normally!" message

Comment: `printf()`, `backtrace()`, `backtrace_symbols(), and `exit()` are all async-signal-**unsafe** functions.  Per the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html):  *when a signal interrupts an unsafe function and the signal-catching function calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined.*  See also the Linux `signal` man page at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: @Andew yes I agree with your point . How can I solve my problem can you please help me out.  My actual requirement is to implement server which doesn't crashes.  Request will come from server So received request I am giving child process to do some operation using request .   When request is processed from child it tell parent I am done using message queue and exit. If some bad happened in child It collect the backtrace and give to parent

Answer (score 1):

From [`wait()`'s Linux docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html):

> WIFEXITED(wstatus)
>                 returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by
>                 calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().

The child signal handler ends the process using `exit()`, so everything works a specified.

Remove the call to `exit()` *from the signal handler* to get the expected result.

---

The call to `raise()` *inside* the signal handler most likely leads to recursive calls, so remove is as well.